# Why i get error in GetUpdatesAsync in telegram bot in c#?

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm new in telegram bot and write this code for check message coming to bot :

```
 var updates = await Bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset);
     foreach (var update in updates)
     {
        if (update.Message.Text.Contains("hi") || update.Message.Text.Contains("Hi"))
           {
             //for first time that code work correct but after 4 hourse in this line

             var updates = await Bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset);
           }
    }
```

get  error but i can not read error because after 1 minute reset visual studio that error solve,what happen?how can i solve that problem?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the desktop application, it's best to use a timer that invokes your code every 1 second

```
   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      yourGetUpdateFunc();
    }

   void yourGetUpdateFunc(){
     var updates = await Bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset);
     foreach (var update in updates)
     {
        if (update.Message.Text.Contains("hi") || update.Message.Text.Contains("Hi"))
       {
          // do work
       }
      }
   }
```